Dual mode in SExtractor
I wanted to use SExtractor for source detection. I have 7 NIRCam filter data from the JWST CEERS catalogue. How can i proceed with the source detection. I read about using dual image mode in which a detection image is to be used.But how are we using multiple filters and then making a single catalogue of sources?
I have f115w, f150w, f200w, f277w, f356w, f410w, f444w filter data.
